# SAS: Interesting Excel Import discrepancy

Tags: import, sas, proc, sas-studio

I'm importing a file from excel which looks like this:

```
Row Col Bucket
1   2   01
2   2   00

%Macro ImportExcel(DF = , OF = , Type = , SheetName = );

proc import datafile = &DF 
out = &OF dbms = &Type replace;
sheet = "&Sheetname";
run;

%Mend;
%ImportExcel(DF = "C:\Users\89974114\Documents\Book1.xlsx" , OF = Book1 ,     TYPE = xlsx , SheetName = Sheet1);
```

when I import the file the dataset looks like this

```
Row Col Bucket
1   2   1
2   2   0
```

Essentially, I lose my custom format from excel and it reverts to the no default, no leading zero's format - is there a way around this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a way to apply informats when using proc import - it's kind of a blunt instrument. You could simply add a short data step inside your macro like:

```
[proc import block]

data &OF ;
  set &OF ;
format Bucket z2.;
run;

%Mend;
```

Or, if you want to convert it to a character string, change the format line to `BucketC = put(Bucket,z2.);`

EDIT: Of course, the superior way is to use PROC DATASETS to modify the format, but that was too obvious for my dumb brain.